# Java асинхронный/не блокирующий InetAddress.getByName

Tags: java, сокет, асинхронность, nio2

Здравствуйте пишу однопоточную программу на java работающую с помощью nio.

Мне нужно создавать сокет по домену и я использую `InetAddress.getByName`, но он блокирующий и при первом вызове с данным аргументом может выполнятся чуть ли не секунды, как получить `InetAddress` не блокируя поток и желательно без дополнительных потоков или с константным их количеством?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать асинхронный dns-запрос не выйдет. По крайней мере без сторонних библиотек. Придётся использовать [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) и [future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
Future<InetAddress> future = executor.submit(() -> InetAddress.getByName(dnsName));

while (true) {  // Цикл событий
    if (!future.isDone())
        continue;

    InetAddress addr = future.get();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Это все-же задействует лишние потоки, а без них нельзя?

Comment: Неа. Даже в Netty разрешение доменных имён делается в отдельном потоке. Как ни крути, а совсем от блокирующих операций не отделаться. На этот случай стоит иметь небольшой пул потоков.